# How to Add Music to iPod nano 7th Generation

Tags: 14.04, rhythmbox, banshee, ipod

I miss my Mac, but prefer Ubuntu. But I still use my iPod and would like to add some new music to it.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.  I have a 7th Generation iPod nano.  I am not able to add songs to it using Banshee, Rhythmbox, commandline, etc.

I've followed suggestions and instructions from Ubuntu Forums and others, but nothing seems to work.  Basically, in Banshee and Rhythmbox I add my music to the Queue then try to drag the song to the iPod listed in the left-side.  But the iPod never take it.

I noticed that songs on my iPod are in M4A and on my Ubuntu machine I have mp3's. Not sure if that's an issue, so I tried to convert a song to m4a, but that did not work either.

Anyone have any luck with a 7th Gen ipod and Ubuntu 18.04?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found this today:  https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/music-player-newipod.html.en

copied from above url:

> > My new iPod won’t work
> >     If you have a new iPod that has never been connected to a computer before, it won’t be recognized properly when you connect it to a Linux computer. This is because iPods need to be set up and updated using the iTunes software, which only runs on Windows and Mac OS.

To set up your iPod, install iTunes on a Windows or Mac computer and plug it in. You will be led through a few steps to set it up. If asked for the Volume Format, choose MS-DOS (FAT), Windows or similar. The other format (HFS/Mac) does not work as well with Linux.

Once you have finished setup, the iPod should work normally when you plug it into a Linux computer.